# Creating product matrix for magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

Currently i am messing with one requirement in magento which is something related to creating a product matrix for t shirt products, which will look something like this :

[image]

Till i researched on google i got it will be done by configurable products, or can it done via eu.linnlive.com this extension, or i have to create grouped product with attributes, if anyone can give me proper way to do this task in magento then it will be very helpful, i just want the way to do this. and is this thing will done by extra coding part or only by using magento default features.

Comment: I'm very interested in this, I got the same problem, the closer thing I found is http://www.magemechanics.com/product-grid-options.html

Comment: @Matteo me and my teammate did this man, we have to write ton of custom code for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I saw that seems to be the only viable solution, thank you for your time, have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

You can try use this module, or create your own. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-matrix.html

For this functionality I think you should use configurable products based on 2 attributes, color & size. Grouped products usually used for a sets of simple products which don't linked by attributes

Comment: Can you provide a bit brief illustration on this, or any logic to program or code, actually i want to do this without purchasing any extension. So it will be really very kind of you if you can provide any logic, flow, code or any detailed discription. Thanks in advance.